# Why do such change in color happens in VS Code while some typo is created?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

Can someone help me with it why do we see such color change in VS Code (I haven't checked with other Editors)? Have you ever faced such a condition? I know it might be due to some error/bug or syntax error in the code but I am not quite sure what is its exact reason.

Underlined section(not link) shows different color:

[image: Underlined section(not link) shows different color]

Comment: Do those characters use weird Unicode code points? What extensions are you using?

Comment: inspect the Textmate classes these characters are in and find out whats different compared to the other text. Try with all extensions disabled. Also look with the hexeditor which unicode points are used.

Comment: @Chris I am using Brack Pair Colorizer ofr VS Code. I just disabled the extension and it didn't replicated the issue. Thank you!

Comment: @rioV8 Actually its just a data that I am using to work with higher order funcitons.I am unknown about the hexeditor and Texmate class that you are referring in my file.